# restar un mes a la fecha actual

Tags: php, date

Hola amigos estoy tratando de obtener los últimos 12 meses, basados en el mes actual:

```
$meses = [];
while ($cstr < 13) {
    $PVDMonth       = date("Y-m", strtotime("-$cstr months"));
    $PVDMonth       = explode('-', $PVDMonth);
    $meses [$cstr] = $PVDMonth;
    ++$cstr;
}
```

el problema es que `date("Y-m", strtotime("-$cstr months"))` me esta devolviendo algo que no es o lo estoy haciendo mal.

para hoy `2021-05-31 10:47:25` me devuelve `2021-05`

lo he probado con:

```
echo date("Y-m", strtotime("-1 months"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder lograr restar o sumar días, meses necesitas transformar la fecha a `strtotime` esto te convierte la fecha en unix te adjunto un ejemplo de como podría restar lo que necesitas:

```
$fecha='2021-05';
$nuevafecha = strtotime('-1 months', strtotime($fecha));
$nuevafecha = date('Y-m' , $nuevafecha);
echo $nuevafecha;
Resultado obtenido: 2021-04
```

Al transformar: `strtotime($fecha)` te devuelve el unix: `1617260400`

Una vez obtenida la fecha ya puedes hacer la operación de restar el mes.

Comment: gracias, es correcto de la manera que lo tengo creo que resta solo 30 dias o el equivalente a un mes, y no resta el mes completo